# Trying to create and Rename sheet in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create and rename a worksheet in VB.Net, but I keep getting the following error. Does anyone mind having a look?

```
    ' Start Excel and get Application object.
    Dim appXL As Excel.Application
    appXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    appXL.Visible = False

    'Intialize this workbook and worksheet
    Dim engwb As Excel.Workbook
    engwb = appXL.ActiveWorkbook

    'Dim texas As Excel.Worksheet
    With engwb
        Dim texas As Excel.Worksheet = engwb.Sheets.Add("Job Info") 'error orccurs here
    End With
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rafY1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
    'Dim texas As Excel.Worksheet
    With engwb
        Dim texas As Excel.Worksheet = New Excel.Worksheet()
        texas = engwb.Sheets.Add("Job Info") 'error orccurs here
    End With
```